# Notification for favourite questions

Tags: feature-request, notifications

I like the feature of adding questions to your favourites, but I'd love to get a notification in my inbox when new answers were given to them or when the question has been updated. Is this a feature I've overlooked? If not, maybe it's a nice idea for the future?

Comment: As far as I remember it was requested, and declined, pretty many times here and on MSO.

Comment: @jeroen- :) couple of days back, I was thinking about to post the same feature request. :)

Comment: @Mołot: Sorry, I didn't know about that. I couldn't find a related question...

Comment: @Jeroen nothing to be sorry about. And I think it was on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ not here.